# Influence vs. Effect

Tags: synonyms

How are these two nouns different when used in scientific papers? I'm not an English speaker and was having a hard time choosing the proper word.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An *effect* happens on account of a prior *cause*.  (well, generally, it is prior. There are some weird cases in quantum mechanics).

An *influence* directs things towards an outcome.

In terms of science education, I have a B.S. in Chemistry, and I cannot imagine a case where I would use *influence* in a scientific paper. Generally, I would use this word to describe how people *affect* one another and help change their views (note the spelling of this different word closer in meaning to *influence* than *effect*).

Comment: Thanks. It's quite easy to tell the difference now. I believe there're cases where influence is used, e.g., when you predict a possible outcome. Right? Just a thought.

Comment: I think I would generally say *affected* the outcome rather than *influenced* the outcome. But I could say something like "The position of the sun influenced the course of the boat."

Answer (score -1):

Influence means the thing that contributes to the effect.

The effect on the other hand is the end-state.